# Is that hyperbolic identity correct?

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

Given the expression:

\begin{equation}
|x|\cosh(kx)+x\sinh(kx), \;\; k>0
\end{equation}

By taking cases for $x$, we have:

\begin{equation}
\bullet \quad x>0: x(\cosh(kx)+\sinh(kx))=x\left( \frac{e^{kx}+e^{-kx}}{2}+\frac{e^{kx}-e^{-kx}}{2}\right)=xe^{kx} \\
\bullet \quad x<0: -x(\cosh(kx)-\sinh(kx))=-x\left( \frac{e^{kx}+e^{-kx}}{2}-\frac{e^{kx}-e^{-kx}}{2}\right)=-xe^{-kx}
\end{equation}

Is it then possible to claim, due to the above, that:

\begin{equation}
|x|\cosh(kx)+x\sinh(kx)=|x|e^{k|x|}, k>0
\end{equation}

holds?

Thank you!

Comment: Should the last line read: $|x| e^{k|x|}$? Otherwise this looks good to me.

Comment: I edited your question just a tad; added parenthesis etc.  Cheers!

Comment: @Joel Correct, thanks!

Comment: @RobertLewis The expression is the product of $|x|$ with $\cosh (kx)$, and not with the whole rest of the expression. I corrected it :) Thank you for your time!

Comment: Oooops!  Sorry about that!  I overlooked your factor of $x$ in the $\sinh$ term!  Guess I need new glasses!  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Let's check:

\begin{equation}
|x|e^{k|x|} = \begin{cases}
x e^{kx} & \text{if } x \geq 0, \\
-x e^{-kx} & \text{if } x < 0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Yes, it works.